# Mi analizador no reconoce puntos decimales!

Tags: c

Estoy trabajando en un analizador hecho en lenguaje C pero al momento de reconocer números con punto decimal los muestra como un entero, es decir, en el archivo que mando llamar (prueba.txt) tengo operaciones tipo "0.23+14*536-25.369" y me muestra "023, +, 14, *, 536, 25369"; si me reconoce operadores de números pero los decimales no.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<string.h>
   #include<ctype.h>

   int isKeyword(char buffer[]){
   char keywords[32][10] = {};
   int a, b = 0;

   for(a = 0; a < 32; ++a){
       if(strcmp(keywords[a], buffer) == 0){
           b = 1;
           break;
       }
   }

   return b;
   }

 int main(){
     char ch, buffer[15], operators[] = "+-*/=";
     FILE *fp;
     int a,j=0;

   fp = fopen("prueba.txt","r");

   if(fp == NULL){
       printf("No existe el documento\n");
       exit(0);
   }

   while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
       for(a = 0; a < 6; ++a){
            if(ch == operators[a])
               printf("%c es un operador\n", ch);
       }
    
       if(isalnum(ch)){
           buffer[j++] = ch;
       }
       else if((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') && (j != 0)){
               buffer[j] = '\0';
               j = 0;
                            
               if(isKeyword(buffer) == 1)
                   printf("%s es una letra\n", buffer);
               else
                   printf("%s es un numero\n", buffer);
       }
    
   }

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
   }
```

¿Podrían ayudarme a decirme donde está mi error?

Comment: [`isalnum()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalnum/) retorna verdadero solo con numeros decimales y letras mayusculas o minusculas, el punto no es ninguno de esos dos

Comment: lo cambie por un isgraph() pero ahora el detalle está en que al momento de reconocer un operador, imprime en pantalla que por ejemplo "/ es un operador" y enseguida "/ es un número", pero ya imprime los números tipo 4.25

Comment: podrias haber añadido un or al lado del `isalnum()` para verificar si el carácter es un punto..